# php curl exec output not written in log file via crontab

Tags: php, curl, cron

I'd like to have the result of my curl exec var written in a log file via crontab.

When I execute manually my script, I have a message saying something like "success" or "fail". The end of my php script looks like this :

```
$res = curl_exec($curl); 
echo $res;//"update detected" or "no update detected" message
curl_close($curl);
```

my crontab looks like this :

```
01 * * * * php <full path>/file.php >> <full path>/file.log 2>&1
```

When the script is executed via the cron, my file.log is empty !?!

Testing more beyond, I made the following :

```
$res = curl_exec($curl); 
echo "result:".$res;"update detected" or "no update detected" message
curl_close($curl);
```

my file.log has now `result:` but not the content of my `$res` variable

What am I doing wrong ?
Thank you for your help
Andreas

I would like the content of my curl_exec() variable written in a log file via crontab

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php ...it will return the result on success, **false on failure**.

Comment: Presumably the curl result is either blank or it failed. You'll need to do some more detailed debugging

Comment: `var_dump($res)` gives what?

Comment: Thank you Shingo for your answer. My concern is not about the output message of the curl_exec, but rather why it is not written in the log file while being executed by the crontab, while I can see it when executing manually on the browser. Actually, it is always "successfully" but depending the scenario, the message can be different.

Comment: use `var_dump($res)` to see what output. Also use `cur_error()` to check in case any error occur

Comment: Make sure the File has 644 permission and its parent folder have 755 permission

Comment: var_dump() gives me : string(88) "{"code":200,"message":"Files uploaded successfully! No update since last time"}" . In the cron log file, it is empty while I expect the message being written in the log file.

Everything works fine, it is just the curl_exec() variable that is not written in the log

Comment: I do not think that there is a permission file/folder issue. When crontab executed, it creates the log file if not exists

Comment: _"Everything works fine, it is just the curl_exec() variable that is not written in the log"_ - there is no way that the "result:" part of `echo "result:".$res;` ends up in your log file, but the content of `$res` doesn't. That $res is empty or false really _is_ the only logical explanation here. So you need to go and figure out why your request gets a different response, when you execute it in the cron context.

Comment: Thanks CBroe fully agree with what you wrote. This is exactly my concern while I cannot see the difference between executing the script manually vs via the crontab. On the other hand, I can see the execution of the job in the syslog.

Comment: What makes you think it is always "successfully"? Have you ever tried it in CLI with the same cron user?

Comment: Thank shingo for your comment. Everything is successfully because the end result is ok (outlook calendar correctly displayed on a tv screen). On the other hand, the windows scheduler made the job and I migrate all this on an ubuntu to have something more robust (in my opinion). I did not try the CLI

Comment: "_I did not try the CLI_"How did you execute your script manually then? Do you have error_reporting turned on? Same PHP versions on web/CLI? cURL installed?

Comment: Well my wrong, sorry guys. It is not working as fine as I said. I have a 65 curl error (When doing a send operation curl had to rewind the data to retransmit, but the rewinding operation failed.). "just" need to fix this...